# background color transition in few seconds w/o JQuery

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/dRKKEY

```css
.back {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">

  Fun place to stay. We got a golf cart to see the rest of the island, but the house is well-equipped and comfortable. Vanessa was kind to pick us up and make golf cart rental arrangements. We were here on our honeymoon, it was perfect for a memorable trip!
  Hosts easily available

</div>
```

I want that yellow background should change with time to yellow, but I want to do ith through CSS. there is enough solution available on StackOverflow that do it with Jquery, but can we achieve this through CSS so that it works on all the browser.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp i tried this, but it roll backs to the original color. How to make th after color permanent.

Comment: please give a shot to css-animations. You can not just ask a question without providing your code that you have attempted. Try out css animations and if you face any issues, post your code here. Thanks.

Comment: If I was knowing the code I wouldn't have posted the question sir.

Comment: you want the yellow background to change over time to yellow? seems to me like that's already happening

Comment: You can do this using CSS Animations. Go to this link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp 
Try learning how to do css animation. IF you face any issues then post the code that you have written for creating css animation.

Comment: SORRY WHITE....

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp i tried this, but it roll backs to the original color. How to make th after color permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below updated code. you need to add 'animation-fill-mode: forwards' to stop the animation once its completed.

```
.back {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {background-color: yellow;}
    to {background-color: white;}
}

@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: yellow;}
    to {background-color: white;}
}
```

Comment: Boss yours solution workled. did u downvote me? why? I am not a spammer. it was a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [keyframe animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations):

```
@keyframes background-change {
    to { background-color: hotpink; }
}

.block {
    animation: background-change 900ms forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.back {
  margin:20px;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100%{
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}



@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100%{
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

It will change change color infinite amount of time from yellow to white back to yellow to make it look smooth.

Comment: @AdiYogi Nope, I didn't. That first comment in your questions ask for code you have tried so he may have downvoted. When i seen your post i've see nyou have tried some stuff so no reason to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for.

```
.block {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.block:hover {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

Comment: It is not about hovering.

Comment: While this gets the color transition job done, it doesn't sound as if OP wants it to be triggered by a hover.

Comment: @AdiYogi How should it trigger then? When you scroll past it or when the page is loaded?

Comment: when page is loaded.

Comment: so what you get from output

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```css
.back {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 100px;
  // background: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes example {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="back">

  Fun place to stay. We got a golf cart to see the rest of the island, but the house is well-equipped and comfortable. Vanessa was kind to pick us up and make golf cart rental arrangements. We were here on our honeymoon, it was perfect for a memorable trip!
  Hosts easily available

</div>
```

Comment: This seems to jump back to the initial color once the animation is done. (Also, why not use the colors as specified by OP?)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp i tried this, but it roll backs to the original color. How to make the after color permanent.